# Devise Wrong number of arguments (13 for 2) upon Omniauthable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to follow this tutorial to implement Google Sign In With Devise into my rails app: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Getting this error:
[image: error]

My routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
```

Omniauthable controller: `app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    puts @user
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Google") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      puts "WENT INTO HERE---------"
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :rememberable, :trackable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[google_oauth2]




  # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      # user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.image_url = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
end
```

I have identified the 13 arguments that the app is referring to, from the session dump:

```
warden.user.user.key: {"id"=>204, "uid"=>"*******", "first_name"=>"First name", "last_name"=>"last name", "provider"=>"google_oauth2", "image_url"=>"*****", "email"=>"***", "has_logged_in"=>false, "created_at"=>"2018-03-17T21:26:24.782Z", "updated_at"=>"2018-03-17T23:31:38.220Z", "admin"=>false}
```

But I don't know where this came from or how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was but after closing my browser, the problem was fixed. So it probably had something to do with my cache.